Allow ingress and egress for one container in docker-compose setup
I want to set up Paperless-ngx on a VM that has no IPv4 address. My old setup on a RaspberryPi at home worked flawlessly. It was able to fetch eMails and to serve requests.
On the VM I only manage to enable either being able to serve requests or to reach the internet. I do not manage to enable both at the same time. I tried to follow plenty of tutorials on the internet but to no avail. I must miss something.
My /etc/docker/daemon.json looks like this:
{
    "experimental": true,
    "fixed-cidr-v6": "fd00::/80",
    "ip6tables": true,
    "ipv6": true,
    "userland-proxy": false
}

With it, directly started container can reach the internet. For instance, inside a fresh Debian container, using docker run --rm -it debian:bookworm bash, I can reach internet, e.g. by apt update, apt install and curl or ping after that.
However, that does not suffice for my docker-compose setup to reach internet.
The docker-compose.yml looks as follows:
version: "3.8"
services:
  broker:
    image: docker.io/library/redis:7
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/data
    networks:
      - paperless-net

  db:
    image: docker.io/library/postgres:16
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /persistent-data/paperless-ngx/database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: paperless
      POSTGRES_USER: paperless
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: paperless
    networks:
      - paperless-net

  webserver:
    image: paperlessngx/paperless-ngx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db
      - broker
    ports:
      - "[::]:24471:8000"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-fs", "-S", "--max-time", "2", "http://localhost:8000"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - /persistent-data/paperless-ngx/data:/usr/src/paperless/data
      - /persistent-data/paperless-ngx/media:/usr/src/paperless/media
      - /persistent-data/paperless-ngx/export:/usr/src/paperless/export
      - /persistent-data/paperless-ngx/consume:/usr/src/paperless/consume
    env_file: docker-compose.env
    environment:
      PAPERLESS_REDIS: redis://broker:6379
      PAPERLESS_DBHOST: db
    networks:
      - paperless-net

networks:
  paperless-net:
    driver: bridge
    enable_ipv6: true
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: fd00:dead:beef::/80

volumes:
  redisdata:

With this configuration, it is possible to access internet from the webserver. However, neither does curl -L http://paperless.my-domain.com work, nor curl -L http://localhost:24471. Weirdly, using the public IPv6 address directly does work: curl -L http://[2001:db8::1]:24471.
What would I have to do to enable ingress and egress in this scenario?

That is not a valid public IPv6 address. All public IPv6 addresses are in the 2000::/3 range.

I am aware of that. I did not want to expose the IPv6 address to my service on StackOverflow.

That is why IANA has set aside the 2001:db8::/32 for such things. If you show illegitimate use of IP addressing, then we may think you have that problem, but using the properly reserved addressing will let us know you are obfuscating the real addresses, not making a big mistake.

I ended up using the internal IPv6 address instead of localhost. I still do not understand why localhost does not work, but using the IPv6 address is fine enough in this case.
Thus, instead of
ProxyPass / http://localhost:24471/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:24471/

I now use
ProxyPass / http://[fd00:0002::1]:24471/
ProxyPassReverse / http://[fd00:0002::1]:24471/

Of course, which address to use depends on your network setup.
